# Run the same function on every item in an array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, animation

It seems I have problems with this whole array thing. Can't get through by myself.
I would like to do something like this:

```
var mcs:Array = ["mc_1","mc_2","mc_3","mc_4"];
var firstMc:Object = mcs.shift();
getStarted();

function getStarted();
{
    getChildByName("firstMc").addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeOut);
}

function fadeOut(event:Event):void 
{ 
    if (firstMc.currentFrame >= 15) 
    { 
        firstMc.gotoAndStop(15);
        firstMc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeOut);
        firstMc = mcs.shift();
        fadeIn();
    } 
    else 
    { 
        firstMc.nextFrame(); 
    } 
}

function fadeIn(event:Event):void
{
    if (firstMc.currentFrame == 30) 
    { 
        firstMc.gotoAndStop(1);
        firstMc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeIn);
        getStarted();
    } 
    else 
    { 
        firstMc.nextFrame(); 
    } 
}
```

**(mcs are 30 frame long tweens with animated alpha value. 0-15frame: fade out, 15-30: fade in)**

So this is the idea. Like a slideshow: mc_1 fade out than mc_2 fade in and fade out than mc_3....etc I could do this in the ugly way: duplicate the functions four times than change the "firstMc" to mc_1 in the first duplicate, mc_2 in the second... but its unefficient. So I would like to ask for some help with these tricky array objects.

Thank you for any advice or example!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is pretty confusing. So I'm just going to cover the part about using arrays.

In your first line:

```
var mcs:Array = ["mc_1","mc_2","mc_3","mc_4"];
```

You've stored an array of strings. You could have instead stored the actual objects by removing the quotation marks, but strings will work too.

So in your case, when you declare your object with:

```
var firstMc:Object = mcs.shift();
```

what you are actually doing is taking the first item from the array, which happens to be a string.

So you should change it to:

```
var firstMc:String = mcs.shift();
```

In getStarted, you use getChildByName, and pass a string correctly, but instead of giving it a string reference to the name of the object you want, you are just giving it another string "firstMc". You should instead give it the variable firstMc that holds the String name of the Object you want to get.

Remove the quotations, and it should work better:

```
function getStarted();
{
    getChildByName(firstMc).addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, fadeOut);
}
```

As for the rest of the code, you could probably achieve the results you want by using animations on the timeline...